# Get File Object from wp.Uploader

Tags: uploads, javascript, plupload, media-modal

I would like to hook into the wp.Uploader and get the FileList object containing the file to be uploaded. So far I've been able to extend the uploader using the code below, but I can't quite seem to find the "before upload" hook.

```
$.extend( wp.Uploader.prototype, {
  success : function( file_attachment ){
    console.log( file_attachment );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't hook it directly as `wp.Uploader` doesn't expose it but you can use its `init()` to hook its internal pluploader instance:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', function () {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        if (typeof wp.Uploader === 'function') {
            $.extend( wp.Uploader.prototype, {
                init : function() { // plupload 'PostInit'
                    this.uploader.bind('BeforeUpload', function(file) {
                        console.log('BeforeUpload file=%o', file);
                    });
                },
                success : function( file_attachment ) { // plupload 'FileUploaded'
                    console.log( file_attachment );
                }
            });
        }
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}, 100 );
```